# Integrate $\int \frac{1-8x^3}{x^2}dx, ~~x\neq{0}$

Tags: integration

Integrate $\int \frac{1-8x^3}{x^2}dx, ~~x\neq{0}$

I don't have a clue how to do this, please can someone help, and give a step-by-step solution?

Comment: Why not just divide the numerator by denominator and integrate term by term?

Comment: What integration rules have you learnt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it:
$$\int ((1-8x^3)x^{-2})~dx$$
$$\int (x^{-2}-8x)~dx$$
$$\int (x^{-2}-8x)~dx = \frac{x^{-1}}{-1}-\frac{8x^2}{2}+c$$
$$=-x^{-1}-4x^2+c$$
Hope this helped!

Comment: No need for you to leave out the d$x$ too!

Comment: Why do you follow all of my posts? The dx isn't important.

Comment: Are you happy now?

Comment: @Jenkins I did not even look to see who had given this answer and I do not remember your name from any other post!

Comment: Put parentheses, please (second and third integrals). $dx$ is very important.: suppose that the integral was using $dy$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: after simple division, the integrand is $\frac{1}{x^2} - 8x$